# Test Equipment for generating large voltage spikes

Tags: voltage, circuit-design, high-voltage, waveform

I am trying to test a tachometer circuit which takes large voltage spikes from an inductive pick up and conditions them for TTL logic. I need input voltages in the order of 200V peak-to-peak but most arbitrary waveform generators generally only go up to 30V peak-to-peak.

What is the correct piece of test equipment to use for this? Do I need to make a custom circuit?

Comment: It depends on waveform, current, frequency and other requirements,  but would a 7:1 transformer after the 30 V P-P waveform generator do?

Comment: I typed into my favorite search engine "high voltage pulse generator" and found a number that meet your specs... Also found several companies that make HV amplifiers (we have one in the lab, works well), and function generators.

Comment: get a cheap 60Hertz power transformer, and wire backwards to the function-generator.

Comment: Yes, the transformer would do the job. Keep in mind, that while tachometer pulses can indeed reach high voltage at high RPM, the currents involved are rather low. And transformer coil will simulate sensor inductance nicely.